# Ubuntu 14.04 gedit error

Tags: text-editor

When I use gedit from the command line in Ubuntu 14.04, after saving a file and exiting gedit I get this:

```
(gedit:6048): Gtk-WARNING **: Calling Inhibit failed: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown: The name org.gnome.SessionManager was not provided by any .service files
```

Is this a problem, or something that requires correction?
And if so, how do I fix this?
Thanks, Paul.

Answer (score 0):

I see that message if running gedit as root, and I have seen it for several different versions of Ubuntu as well as in other Linux distros.  As best I can tell, it's related to the fact that although you are running the application as root, it is running inside a graphical session owned by your user account, and it's attempting to find settings for the root user's graphical desktop.

As long as your files are being saved properly, I wouldn't sweat it, :-)

Comment: Thanks for that information. There seems to be no problem with the file being saved; gedit seems to do all it is supposed to. So as you suggest, I will just ignore this. Paul.